# Joining multiple tables with same foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join

'I have a database where employees are assigned to different projects. Some projects are split into different tasks. The following database structure has been created.'

```
USER:
+------------+-------------+
| Person ID  | Name        | 
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | A           | 
| 2          | B           | 
| 3          | C           | 
+------------+-------------+
PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT:
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| P_Assign key    | Project Key | Person ID |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1               | 1           | 1         | 
| 2               | 1           | 2         |     
| 3               | 1           | 3         |    
+------------+-------------+------+-----+----
TASK ASSIGNMENT:
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| T_Assign key    | Project Key | Person ID |task key|
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| 1               | 2           | 1         | 1      |
| 2               | 2           | 2         | 1      |
| 3               | 2           | 3         | 1      |
| 4               | 2           | 1         | 2      |
| 5               | 2           | 2         | 2      |
| 6               | 2           | 3         | 2      |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+;

'What type of query would be required to get results like this?'

+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| Person ID       | Project Key | Task Key  |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1               | 1           | NULL      | 
| 1               | 2           | 1         | 
| 1               | 2           | 2         |
| 2               | 1           | NULL      |
| 2               | 2           | 1         | 
| 2               | 2           | 2         |
| 3               | 1           | NULL      |
| 3               | 2           | 1         | 
| 3               | 2           | 2         |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---+
```

I have tried a few queries but I think the fact that there are the same foreign keys is preventing me from getting the results i need.

```
SELECT 
 user.person_ID, 
 task_assignment.Project Key, 
 project_assignment.Project Key
FROM user
JOIN dbo.project_assignment 
     ON project_assignment.person_key=user.person_key
LEFT JOIN dbo.task_assignment 
     ON dbo.project_assignment.person_key=dbo.task_assignment.person_key
```

If a project is split into tasks, the person is assigned to the task.
If a project isnt split into task, the person is assigned to the project.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include example code to demonstrate that you have put some effort into solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the sample data, to obtain that same exact result, we'd need to combine two queries.

The first query:

```
SELECT u.person_id
     , p.project_key
     , t.task_key
  FROM user u
  JOIN project_assignment p
    ON p.person_id = u.person_id
  LEFT
  JOIN task_assignment t
    ON t.person_id   = p.person_id
   AND t.project_key = p.project_key
 ORDER 
    BY u.person_id
     , p.project_key
```

will return:

```
person_id  project_key  task_key
---------  -----------  --------
1          1            NULL
2          1            NULL
3          1            NULL
```

And the second query:

```
SELECT u.person_id
     , t.project_key
     , t.task_key
  FROM user u
  JOIN task_assignment t
    ON t.person_id   = u.person_id
 ORDER 
    BY u.person_id     
     , t.project_key
     , t.task_key
```

Will return:

```
person_id  project_key  task_key
---------  -----------  --------
1          2            1
1          2            2
2          2            1
2          2            2
3          2            1
3          2            2
```

The results of those two queries can be combined with a UNION ALL set operator, and then adding an ORDER BY clause, for example:

```
SELECT u.person_id
     , p.project_key
     , t.task_key
  FROM user u
  JOIN project_assignment p
    ON p.person_id = u.person_id
  LEFT
  JOIN task_assignment t
    ON t.person_id   = p.person_id
   AND t.project_key = p.project_key
 UNION ALL
SELECT u.person_id
     , t.project_key
     , t.task_key
  FROM user u
  JOIN task_assignment t
    ON t.person_id   = u.person_id
 ORDER 
    BY person_id
     , project_key
     , task_key IS NOT NULL
     , task_key
```

There's some cases that aren't covered in the example data... what if, for a given user, the same project key appears in both the project_assignment table and the task_assignment tables. What should the output look like? (There may be some adjustments to  be made to the query.)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you haven't really shown what you've done. An example query for this scenario:

```
SELECT p.P_Assign key, p.Project Key, p.Person I FROM PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT p
INNER JOIN TASK ASSIGNMENT t
ON p.Person_ID=t.Person_ID
```

Assuming `person_id` is the primary key of project_assignment and foreign key of task assignment.

This will join the first two together. In your select statement specify the columns you want shown in your results.

Answer (score 0):

I did not actually get the idea what you want here, but I think probably you are looking for this query:

```
SELECT PersonId, ProjectKey, TaskKey
FROM TASK_ASSIGNMENT
GROUP BY PersonId, ProjectKey, TaskKey;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below....

```
Select 
User.Person_ID,
all_tasks.Project_key,
all_tasks.Task_Key
From User 
Left Join  
(
Select Person_ID, Project_Key, Null as Task_Key From Project_Assignment
Union All
Select Person_ID, Project_key, Task_Key From Task_Assignment
) all_tasks On all_tasks.person_ID = User.Person_ID
```